# python selenium get all the divs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website and get all the `div` elements in the HTML. 
The webpage I am trying to access is a page containing job opportunities where each job is inside a separate `div`.
I am trying to get them all so that I can run them through a `for` loop and extract their data for each separately.

I haven't coded it yet.

Is there a specific method or way to get them? **And also I only want to extract the `div`s that contain jobs**.

Outer HTML

```
    <div class="row result clickcard" id="p_1d1829a543b1f3a7" data-jk="1d1829a543b1f3a7" data-tn-component="organicJob" data-tu="">
<h2 id="jl_1d1829a543b1f3a7" class="jobtitle">
    <a href="/rc/clk?jk=1d1829a543b1f3a7&amp;fccid=95ea1992d038e9af&amp;vjs=3" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow" onmousedown="return rclk(this,jobmap[1],0);" onclick="setRefineByCookie([]); return rclk(this,jobmap[1],true,0);" title="Planner II" class="turnstileLink" data-tn-element="jobTitle">Planner II</a>
    - <span class="new">new</span></h2>
<span class="company">
    Vantage Utility Services</span>

 - <span class="location">Upland, CA</span>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="snip">
<div class="">
    <span class="summary">
            Transportation or giving away of up to 28.5 grams of marijuana, other than concentrated <b>cannabis</b>, or the offering to transport or give away up to 28.5 grams of...</span>
    </div>


<div class="result-link-bar-container">
    <div class="result-link-bar"><span class="date">4 hours ago</span> <span id="tt_set_1" class="tt_set">  -  <a id="sj_1d1829a543b1f3a7" href="#" class="sl resultLink save-job-link " onclick="changeJobState('1d1829a543b1f3a7', 'save', 'linkbar', false, ''); return false;" title="Save this job to my.indeed">save job</a> - <a href="#" id="tog_1" class="sl resultLink more-link " onclick="toggleMoreLinks('1d1829a543b1f3a7'); return false;">more...</a></span><div id="editsaved2_1d1829a543b1f3a7" class="edit_note_content" style="display:none;"></div><script>if (!window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']) {window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7'] = {};}window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['showSource'] = false; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['source'] = "Vantage Utility Services"; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['loggedIn'] = false; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['showMyJobsLinks'] = false;window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['undoAction'] = "unsave";window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['relativeJobAge'] = "4 hours ago";window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['jobKey'] = "1d1829a543b1f3a7"; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['myIndeedAvailable'] = true; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['showMoreActionsLink'] = window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['showMoreActionsLink'] || true; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['resultNumber'] = 1; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['jobStateChangedToSaved'] = false; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['searchState'] = "q=Cannabis&amp;fromage=last"; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['basicPermaLink'] = "https://www.indeed.com"; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['saveJobFailed'] = false; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['removeJobFailed'] = false; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['requestPending'] = false; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['notesEnabled'] = true; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['currentPage'] = "serp"; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['sponsored'] = false;window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['reportJobButtonEnabled'] = false; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['showMyJobsHired'] = false; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['showSaveForSponsored'] = false; window['result_1d1829a543b1f3a7']['showJobAge'] = true;</script></div></div>

<div class="tab-container">
    <div id="tt_display_1" class="more-links-container result-tab" style="display:none;"><a class="close-link closeLink" title="Close" href="#" onclick="toggleMoreLinks('1d1829a543b1f3a7'); return false;"></a><div id="more_1" class="more_actions"><ul><li><span class="mat">View all <a href="/q-Vantage-Utility-Services-l-Upland,-CA-jobs.html" rel="nofollow">Vantage Utility Services jobs in Upland, CA</a> - <a href="/l-Upland,-CA-jobs.html">Upland jobs</a></span></li><li><span class="mat">Salary Search: <a href="/salaries/Planner-Salaries,-Upland-CA" onmousedown="this.href = appendParamsOnce(this.href, '?campaignid=serp-more&amp;fromjk=1d1829a543b1f3a7&amp;from=serp-more-nofollow');" rel="&quot;nofollow&quot;">Planner salaries in Upland, CA</a></span></li><li><span class="mat">Learn more about working at <a href="/cmp/Vantage-Utility-Services" onmousedown="this.href = appendParamsOnce(this.href, '?fromjk=1d1829a543b1f3a7&amp;from=serp-more&amp;campaignid=serp-more&amp;jcid=424bbfe9ea0cfaab');">Vantage Utility Services</a></span></li><li><span class="mat">Related forums: <a href="/forum/loc/Upland-California.html">Upland, California</a> - <a href="/forum/job/Planner.html">Planner</a> - <a href="/forum/cmp/Vantage-Utility-Services.html">VANTAGE UTILITY SERVICES</a></span></li></ul></div></div><div class="dya-container result-tab"></div>
    <div class="tellafriend-container result-tab email_job_content"></div>
    <div class="sign-in-container result-tab"></div>
    <div class="notes-container result-tab"></div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you really need to use selenium for this, use html parser maybe ?

Comment: yeah i do, it is a requirement to use selenium. I've done it using Beautifulsoup but I have to covert the whole process to selenium with headless firefox

Comment: *each job is inside a separate div*... so you don't need all the div nodes, but just specific nodes, right? Share HTML of required div. You can also share working `bs4` code

Comment: @Andersson I've edited the question, There are several such `div`s and I need to get them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement below code:

```
div_nodes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.row.result.clickcard")
```

Let me know if you need more specific selector

Comment: thank you, it worked. Is there a complete documentation for web scraping by selenium

Comment: [Here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) you can find documentation. But note that Selenium is not a correct tool for web-scraping. It usually used for test/routine automation

Comment: the use of selenium is to grab the JavaScript based content. Beautifulsoup only get the HTML content. Is there any other way to do this rather than Selenium or Beautifulsoup?

Comment: requests-html, PyQt5, Scrapy... You can also make a direct API request with python-requests to get required data instead of scraping rendered HTML page

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
```

This will return a list of all the div's inside the html.

Answer (score 1):

To get all divs you can use:

> self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div')

It's also possible to get text from entire page by:

> self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').text

But it's really bad idea to get all divs and use for loops. Much better to find proper selector for data, that you want to get from a page, like class/id, and get data just from these elements.